# Global variables not updating in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model-view-controller, global-variables

I want to update a global variable in my MVC application. I'm passing information via my global variable `$foo` but for some reason it is not updating the data in one of my `functions` in the `class`

How can I update the value of `$foo` inside my function?

My code:

```
class example extends CI_Controller {

    private $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = 10;
    }

    public function index() {
        // some code here
        $this->foo = 20;
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    if($this->input->post()) {
       error_log($this->foo);
    }
}
```

It is returning `10` even though I am trying to update the value to `20`

Comment: Its for you a problem setting or assign this variable in the config file or config item? Doing so you can access it with easy in all your controllers, modules, views

Comment: i plan on setting `foo` to equal another variable which is being inside the `index()` function @Franco

Comment: There are no global variables in your code.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you want to do that. What I am trying to say if you use a config item in place of this global var you can manipulate it easily and you can use it everywhere.

Comment: @zerkms how can I update `$foo` inside my function `index()`

Comment: Move `if($this->input->post())` code inside `index()` method so you will actually see the proper output. And as @zerkms said `$foo` is not a global variable but class property.

Comment: @user4756836 `$this->foo = 20;` --- that's how you modify it.

Comment: You closed method before `if` block?

Comment: All those commotion about want to do what is already doen. The config item act already as a global variable.

Comment: Would you like to try again and correct your example code. It's got procedural code flapping in the breeze which should be inside one of your methods. I.E that code simply wont even run!

Comment: the if block should reside inside the index function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing here... but this works.

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    private $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = 10;
    }

    public function index() {
        // some code here
        $this->foo = 20;
        echo $this->foo; // The result is 20 as set.
    }
    // hard coded the setter var name for demonstration purposes only
    public function set_foo($foo){
       $this->foo = $foo;
    }
    // hard coded the getter var name for demonstration purposes only
    public function get_foo(){
       return $this->foo;
    }

}
```

$foo is a "property" of the class which IS accessible to all of it's member "methods". It isn't a GLOBAL as you refer to it. GLOBALS are accessible to everything.

Comment: my issue is that it does echo 20 within the index() function but not outside it... so in my ($this->input->post())... it echo's 10

Comment: I have updated my answer with how you would access your private property called foo... I have hard coded the function names with _foo just for demonstration purposes on the concept. When you want protected data, you control how it is accessed to prevent outside forces changing your values which might be the case if foo were set to public... You might want to go and have a read about classes to help you understand this better.

Comment: it works if i call the setter inside the if statement but doesn't work if i call it inside the index() function. I am starting to think if there is something inside my index() function preventing all this

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are actually wanting to achieve here! I'm not following what it is you think you are doing.